# Share aws_route53_record between terragrunt configs?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

So, I have one terragrunt config for the domain itself, this contains a static domain verification record entry.

Now, I want to add a second "record" to this record from a second config that automates a second process fully within the terragrunt tree.

My idea so far is to create a third module, depending on the other two. Any better ideas?

Edited: Structure so far:

- global

  - domain.com

    - aws_route53_zone - domain.com ``
    - aws_route53_record - _amazonses.domain.com, conflict record
  - ses

    - domain.com

      - aws_route53_record - _amazonses.domain.com, conflict record

However, I think I made things harder than it was. I was able to solve it by reversing the dependency so that the main domain module depends on the ses module.

Comment: Can you share some code so we can give you better advice?

Comment: I added some more structure information to the main entry. I have a possible solution, so maybe I was just making things harder than I had to :)